# Delete string into string

Tags: c#

I have a problem with search and delete string in string.
As you look in the image I want to delete the string between the balise  and  using my code. But it want delete so where is my problem?

```
string chaine = im;
int href = chaine.IndexOf("<a href");
int ahref = chaine.IndexOf("</a>");
string sup = "";
for (int c = href; c < ahref; c++)
{
    sup = sup + chaine[c];
    if (chaine[c] != ahref)
        break;
}
chaine = chaine.Replace(sup, "");
im = chaine;
```

[image: my screen shoot]

Comment: The code you have posted is very unclear.  Please post the method it is contained within.

Comment: what results are you getting? As the sample is an image, we can't easily copy/paste this to determine the unintended result

Comment: You break out of your for loop immediately. `ahref` is an int (the location of the first "</a>" in the string) and `chaine[c]` is a char ("<").

Comment: try remove < in: int ahref = chaine.IndexOf("/a>");

Comment: Additionally, if that image is of the string you're working with, it seems "<a href" and "</a>" don't appear at all, so you won't even go into your loop (since `href == ahref`, so your loop's condition fails immediately).

Comment: Remove the `break`, first of all. The `for` loop will end on its own when `c == ahref`. In addition, this code could be a whole lot simpler and more readable.

Comment: I try to use this methode Boolean verif=false; while (verif) { int start = im.IndexOf("<a href"); int stop = im.IndexOf("</a>"); im = im.Remove(start, stop + 4 - start); if (start > -1) verif = true; } and it isn't work to delete all a href balise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be simplified. Please though add some error checking or at least a try / catch in case the sub-strings are not found.

```
int start = im.IndexOf("<a href");
int stop = im.IndexOf("</a>", start);
im = im.Remove(start, stop + 4 - start) // 4 is the length of the stop string
```

Comment: thnx it work, but only with the first balise href
I try to use this methode
 Boolean verif=false;
                            while (verif)
                            {
                                int start = im.IndexOf("<a href");
                                int stop = im.IndexOf("</a>");
                                im = im.Remove(start, stop + 4 - start);
                                if (start > -1)
                                    verif = true;
                            }
and it isn't work to delete all a href nalise

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try a regex replace.

```
chaine = Regex.replace(chaine, @"\<a(?<attrs>.*)\>.*\<a/\>", m => "<a" + m.Groups["attrs"] + "></a>")
```

Comment: for this code it isn't work, and it delete on the balise not the string between balise